# How to make document library in top level visible to subsites?

Tags: document-library

I have a requirement for a top level portal site to have a document library - pretty easy so far. There will then be sub sites underneath this that need to access this document library, as we are building an intranet and each division of the company is to have its own section, however they want one central location for all documents. This means that all sub sites must be able to view this document library at the portal level. Can a document library under the portal be seen from a subsite - and a specific view applied?

From my research I believe not out of the box and I have found only 1 web part that half does the job from Bamboo Solutions but its very expensive for our needs. The web part in question is the List Roll Web Part.

If anyone has done this before or knows of a suitable web part it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, you can't, without some development.  The question you should ask yourself is : Do we really need a centralized collaboration library?

You can solve the problem by having subsites for each division, and then, have a Records Center where you will store the final versions of every document.  It would do the trick, and will be a lot more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

You can, you just need to do a bit of work with SharePoint designer.

What you do is use a webservice datasource to query the top-level list and display the contents via a dataview. Works in SP2007 and should in SP2010.

Answer (score 1):

Are the departments residing in the same site collection as the portal?  If so, with a proper metadata structure, views, and page viewer web parts, something could be constructed.  A logical metadata structure needs to be hashed out so that the specific departmental files stored in the document library can be properly be identified in a view.  Then the URL to this view is used in a page viewer web part at the subsite for the department.

If you are trying to do it the other way where each department has their own document library and your trying to roll that up, you'll need something like the Content Query web part.  The other alternative is to use the [Lightning Conductor](http://lightningtools.com/list-rollup-web-parts.aspx) web part from [Lightning Tools](http://lightningtools.com/) that's like the Content query web part on steroids.  It can roll up data from sites in different site collections so if these department sites are not in the same site collection as the portal, you can give the appearance that it is.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could have multiple options (provided that permissions are setup accordingly):

- An XSLT View Web Part hardwired to that library, only requires SP-D, and you could expose even editing functions, etc.
- Another alternative, involving a little bit of codding is to use ECMA to effectively load your with a simple CAML query the view you want exposed, or
  use ListData.svc with jSon with CEWP
- Content Query Web Part (with a fixed list targeted, in the same site collection)

  - Custom development

Answer (score 0):

Would any of these proposed solutions allow the subsites to upload documents to the central (top-level) library?